# How to set the version fields of a JIRA ticket from Groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm using JIRA 7.1.4 Server and under Behaviours I'm trying to create a Groovy Initialiser Function for setting default values of form fields, so when the user tries to create a new ticket, some fields are already filled in with default values. This is what I have so far:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def versionManager = ComponentAccessor.getVersionManager()
def versions = versionManager.getVersionsUnreleased(issueContext.projectObject.id, false)
getFieldById("affectedVersion").setFormValue([versions.first().id])
getFieldById("description").setFormValue([versions.first().id])
```

When the dialog for creating a new JIRA ticket opens, this script successfully sets the "Description" field to the right version id (only for debugging purposes), but the "Affects Version/s" field remains empty for some reason.

I think the id of the "Affects Version/s" field is OK, because I got it from JQL, so e.g. the following query displays correct information:

```
project = "--------" and affectedVersion is EMPTY
```

Therefore I assume that I'm trying to set the value of the version field incorrectly, but cannot figure out the mistake. The above Groovy script is based on [this example](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.4/jira/recipes/behaviours/setting-default-fields.html), but the script might be wrong, and I was not able to find more information about `getFieldById` or `setFormValue` [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.1.4/) either.

Can anyone give a working example of setting JIRA's "Affects Version/s" or "Fix Version/s" fields from Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

If you setting fixversion on issue create step in workflow. You need to put this script into first post function(before issue create).

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def versionManager = ComponentAccessor.getVersionManager()
def versions = versionManager.getVersionsUnreleased(issue.getProjectObject().getId(), false)
issue.setAffectedVersions([versions.first()])
```